# Textbox on top of picture

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012

In Reporting Services I'm trying to place a table over a picture. Within the Report Builder it works, but whenever the report is run, the table is moved to beneath the picture. I've thought about several workarounds, but none of them has worked:

1. Creating a rectangle with my picture as the background, and placing the table of top of the rectangle. This works, but it doesn't show the picture in the Excel sheet when exporting the report. I need the picture in the report, so this solution is not satisfactory.
2. Creating a report where the background image is set to the picture I need, and then importing it in my main report as a subreport. The weird thing here is that background images WILL show up in Excel when you just export the report with the background image. However, when importing that report within another report, it doesn't show up anymore in the export.
3. Set the picture as background for the main report. the problem is that the picture will be the background for every page/sheet. If someone nows a possibility to set a specific background per page, I would also be helped!

TL;DR: Is it possible the overlay a table of top of a picture? Or is it possible to set a background image per page, so I can use that instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can overlap text and an image but it may not show up that way depending on how you want to render it. I think it works with PDFs and DOCs but not much else.

You can use a background image for the report or just the table's background.

Click on either the Body or the table and use the **Background Image** properties.

Put an Expression in the Background Image **Value** field with your logic to determine which image to display.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156482(v=sql.100).aspx